# Parse each bit in a byte stream with Python

Tags: python, struct, bit-manipulation, byte, unpack

I have a binary file which holds byte sets to represent different status flags of some modules. Here is an example of a 4 byte structure:

```
7A 05 00 00
```

Which should be (according to a hex->bin converter):

```
0111 1010 0000 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Now I have trouble reading in those bytes and parse them in order (they basically represent true/false values).

If I use `struct.unpack`, I have to use the little endian parsing and unsigned integer I guess, like this:

```
>>> with open('the_file.dat', 'rb') as f:
...     b = f.read(4)
>>> struct.unpack('I', b)[0]
1402
```

If I convert 1402 back to integer, I get totally different bits and of course not 32 bits since the leading zeros are cut off:

```
>>> "{0:b}".format(1402)
'10101111010'
```

So what is the correct way to parse those bits? I'm kind of confused at this point.

UPDATE:

OK I just found out that the format specifier `b` uses big endian to convert an integer to a representing bit-string:

```
>>> struct.unpack('<I', b)[0]
1402
>>> struct.unpack('>I', b)[0]
2047148032
>>> "{0:b}".format(2047148032)
'1111010000001010000000000000000'
```

The leading zero(s) is(are) still missing, so is the only way to parse the bits to fill up with leading zeros until I have the length of 4 bytes (32) like this:

```
>>> "{0:032b}".format(2047148032)
'01111010000001010000000000000000'
```

Comment: Well, my hex editor (Hex Fiend) shows `7A050000` and also 1402 as unsigned int with little endian.

Comment: The [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) module might be a good alternative to using `struct`. It allows you to create arrays of boolean values from the sequence of bytes and would supply leading zero (or `False`) values the way you want. It also supports all the endian variations and is relatively fast since it's written in C.

Answer (score 0):

To get an integer value for a string of hex digits, try using int to convert them. If the octets are separated by spaces, you can use `replace` to remove them:

```
intvalue = int('7A 05 00 00'.replace(' ', ''), base=16)
```

If you want a string representing the binary values, you can use `bin()` to produce a binary string:

```
bin(int('7A 05 00 00'.replace(' ', ''), base=16))
```

yields: `'0b1111010000001010000000000000000'`.

If you want to remove the `'0b'` from the front, you can slice the first two characters off of the string:

```
bin(int('7A 05 00 00'.replace(' ', ''), base=16))[2:]
```

Note that if you want to check specific flags, you should *not* use the string form, but rather use the bitwise operators on the integer form to check specific bits. To check if bit `i` is set, you can use:

```
intval & (1 << i) != 0
```